# Fortran Cascading Optional Arguments

Tags: fortran, option-type

I am having a problem with using optional arguments. I have two routines `num_to_str` and `qry` that take a format `fm` as an optional argument. When I call `qry ("lc")`, even though
`fm` is not present, the routine `num_to_str` thinks `fm` is present.

```
Call qry ("lc")

Subroutine qry (lb, fm)
  Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: lb, fm
  Real :: n 
  Character (Len=65) :: s 

  n = 90.0
  Call num_to_str (n, s, fm)
End Subroutine

Subroutine num_to_str (nb, s, fm)
  Real, Intent (In) :: nb
  Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: s
  Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: fm

  fmt = "*"
  if (Present (fm)) fmt = Trim (fm)
End Subroutine
```

Comment: Are explicit interfaces accessible for both subroutines in the scopes in which they are referenced?

Comment: `num_to_str` is in module `core` whereas `qry` is in module `lattice`. `Present (fm)` in `qry` is returning `T`, however when I try to print `fm` I am getting invalid memory reference.

Comment: What compiler/compile options?  For the example code shown (note no declaration is present for `fmt`) `present(fm)` should not be true.

Comment: gfortran -ffree-form -g -J./build/lib. I agree with you, `present (fm)` should be false.

Comment: Which compiler version? Try to make a self-contained compilable example.

Comment: As written, your program does not compile, for the following reasons: a) no `END` statement for the main program b) fmt is undeclared and gets a default type of `REAL` which clashes with the assignment of `"*"` c) an explicit interface for `num_to_str` is required in the subroutine `qry` for passing on the optional argument `fm` to `num_to_str` d) gfortran is clever enough to diagnose that `qry` has an optional argument, and it also has not explicit interface.  Please fix these problems by editing your original question.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is solved, but the problem is not occurring this time. Might be that one of the object files was not updated

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with both intel fortran and gfortran,

```
module stuff
  implicit none

contains 

  Subroutine qry (lb, fm)
    Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: lb, fm
    Real :: n 
    Character (Len=65) :: s

    n = 90.0
    s = "test"
    Call num_to_str (n, s, fm)
  End Subroutine

  Subroutine num_to_str (nb, s, fm)
    Real, Intent (In) :: nb
    Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: s
    Character (Len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: fm
    Character (Len=65)  :: fmt

    fmt = "*"
    if (Present (fm)) then 
        fmt = Trim (fm)
        print*, nb, s, fm
    else
        print*, nb, s
    endif
  End Subroutine  

end module stuff

program test
  use stuff, only : qry

  Call qry("lc")
  Call qry("lc","f12")

end program test
```

With output

```
 $ ./a.out 
 90.000000     test                                                             
 90.000000     test               f12
```

With optional arguments, you should always use modules (or an explicit interface). Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402647/how-could-a-simple-optional-argument-lead-to-data-corruption)